# godoc http server doesn't seem to live reload changes

Tags: go, godoc

I seem to be unable to find an answer to the question, does the godoc server support live reload changes in for my own projects?

According to [this article](http://whipperstacker.com/2015/10/03/run-a-godoc-server-locally-to-see-documentation-for-unpublished-packages/) it should be supported however whenever I change my code (update documentation) no changes appear until restart of the web server

My documentation updates/appear every time I start the the sever:

```
godoc -http=:6060 &
```

I don't want to restart the server for every change, is this expected behavior, what can I do to update my changes with the least amount of effort?

My go version:

```
$ go version
go version go1.8 darwin/amd64
```

Using browser with incognito mode:

```
Chrome Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)
```

Comment: It auto-reloads docs for me perfectly, works as intended. I changed something in docs in go source, refreshed page in browser, and I saw the changes. Need more info.

Comment: Maybe it's a browser caching issue? Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Godoc for a directory ("Directory /src/github.com/someuser" at the top) does not automatically update.

Godoc for a package ("Package yourthing" at the top) will automatically update, but you must reload the page to see the change.

Comment: This is disappointing to hear; is there any plan to fix the problem?